# How to prevent Spring AuthenticationProvider to execute for static or image resources?

Tags: java, spring

I have a java web Spring Boot application with some custom Spring Sceurity configuration. When I run my app the images are executing the AuthenticationProvider and it is causing me an exception (due to the fact I do some updates when the user first logs in).

How can I prevent the AuthenticationProvider to run when images are accessed?

My configuration is below:

```
@Order(1)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BaseSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint restUnauthorizedEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler      restAccessDeniedHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Ignoring resources in Spring Security");
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/images/*")
                .antMatchers("/app/errors/*.html");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws SecurityConfigException {
        try {
              http
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager())
                    .antMatchers("/api/users/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(restUnauthorizedEntryPoint)
                    .accessDeniedHandler(restAccessDeniedHandler)

                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                    .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())

                .and()
                .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()

                .and();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new SecurityConfigException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public AffirmativeBased accessDecisionManager() {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<>();
        decisionVoters.add(new WebExpressionVoter());
        decisionVoters.add(new RoleHierarchyVoter(roleHierarchy()));
        return new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
    }

    /**
     * Create the role hierarchy as an implementation of Spring Security {@link RoleHierarchyVoter} where the Spring
     * roles are created from a combination of {@link Module}_{@link Role}. The AccessDecisionVoter provided with Spring
     * Security expects the role names to begin with the prefix 'ROLE_'. The hierarchy is as follows:
     * <p/>
     * {@code ROLE_COMMON_ADMIN > ROLE_COMMON_USER_ADMIN } and {@code ROLE_COMMON_ADMIN > ROLE_CUSTOM_USER}
     */
    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy() {
        StringBuilder h = new StringBuilder();

        // Common tree, root is COMMON_ADMIN
        appendIncludesRule(h, Module.COMMON, Role.ADMIN, Module.COMMON, Role.USER_ADMIN);

        // Custom tree, root is COMMON_ADMIN
        appendIncludesRule(h, Module.COMMON, Role.ADMIN, Module.CUSTOM, Role.USER);

        RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        roleHierarchy.setHierarchy(h.toString());
        return roleHierarchy;
    }

    private void appendIncludesRule(StringBuilder h, Module lModule, Role lRole, Module rModule, Role rRole) {
        h.append(GrantedAuthorityFactory.ROLE_PREFIX).append(lModule).append('_').append(lRole).append('>');
        h.append(GrantedAuthorityFactory.ROLE_PREFIX).append(rModule).append('_').append(rRole).append(' ');
    }

    /**
     * Creates a replacement CsrfTokenRepository for use by Spring CSRF protection. It looks for a header called
     * X-XSRF-TOKEN, which AngularJS sets by default. AngularJS obtains this from the XSRF-TOKEN cookie (set in
     * CsrfHeaderFilter).
     * 
     * @return CsrfTokenRepository
     */
    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName(CSRF_HEADER_NAME);
        return repository;
    }
}
```

And the second configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Profile({ "prod" })
public class UidSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserAccountService  userAccountService;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Ignoring resources in Spring Security");
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/images/*")
                .antMatchers("/app/errors/*.html");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        LOG.info("AuthenticationManagerBuilder: PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider configured");
        auth.authenticationProvider(preauthAuthProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws SecurityConfigException {
        try {
            http.addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class);
            http.headers().cacheControl().disable();
        } catch (SecurityConfigException ex) {
            LOG.error("SecurityConfigException:", ex);
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("SecurityConfigException:", ex);
            throw new SecurityConfigException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preauthAuthProvider() {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preauthAuthProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        preauthAuthProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceWrapper());
        return preauthAuthProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> userDetailsServiceWrapper() {
        UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> wrapper = new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<>();
        wrapper.setUserDetailsService(userAccountService);
        return wrapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public SsoHeaderFilter ssoFilter() throws SecurityConfigException {
        SsoHeaderFilter filter = new SsoHeaderFilter();
        try {
            filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("SsoHeaderFilter Excpetion:", ex);
            throw new SecurityConfigException(ex);
        }
        return filter;
    }
}
```

I really don't understand why AuthenticationProvider is executing for images even after I had configured Spring to ignore all /images/* pattern.

If I F5 the home screen I don't get the exception (because the update was made the first time the user accessed the app) but the Auth provider seem to be running yet.

**EDIT**

Image path: images/mylogo.png

Answer (score 0):

I think your antMatchers might be a little off.

Try `/images/**` instead of `/images/*` and for static pages try `/app/**/*.html`

Here is an example from JHipster.  CSS and Images live under the content directory:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
        .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
        .antMatchers("/bower_components/**")
        .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
        .antMatchers("/content/**")
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
        .antMatchers("/test/**");
}
```

Comment: If changing the images `antMatcher` fixes it for you, I'm guessing you were referencing images in nested directories (i.e. /images/avatars/1.png) rather than directly from images (i.e. /images/logo.png)

Comment: The image path is "images/mylogo.png", so the antMatcher looks fine.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the server with "prod" profile in your test environment?  Or is it only happening in test because you don't run with "prod" profile locally?

Comment: Forget about the environment thing. I missed that profile difference. 
Anyway. I logged PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider and it runs twice when the application is called. The second call fails because the user entity is updated again with auditing information and an OptimisticLock occurs in Hibernate. I believe that provider should only execute once, correct? How do I check which resource triggered its execution?

Comment: Look at thread stack at each breakpoint.  It's probably being invoked by one of your filters each time. See if it's the same filter both times or a different one. Then inspect HttpServletRequest inside the filter to determine resource being requested.

Comment: It turns out that Spring Security is executing PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider for every resource, even for those configured to be ignored (images, css, fonts). 

I was expecting Spring to run it only once, when loading the index.html page first and only after that load all resources. But looks likes auth provider is executed for all resources, even if the user was already authenticated. How can I prevent that provider to run after the user is successfully authenticated? And also prevent it to run for ignored resources?

Comment: Looks a little better now. I removed the method `configure(WebSecurity web)` from ***UidSecurityConfig*** and updated the method `configure(HttpSecurity http)` with: 

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/fonts/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/lib/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class);

Comment: Now it looks the authentication is happening only once, but the ***SsoHeaderFilter*** is executing for all resources, even for those configured with ***permitAll()***. 

The ***configure(WebSecurity web)*** method is called after ***configure(HttpSecurity http)*** when application is loading. This could be a reason for spring not ignoring the resources?

Is there a built in way to make ***SsoHeaderFilter*** not run for the ignored resources (urls)?

I had to override method `doFilter()` in the ***SsoHeaderFilter*** and implemented it to ignore some URIs (static resources). Smells but...